# Series of books about a grassland princess who studies at the fire temple but is forced to leave for an arranged marriage

Tags: story-identification, books

The book starts with the princess of a grassland nation who has an affinity for fire so she is in training at the fire temple.  Her sister has an affinity for water (pretty sure it’s water but may also be air) and studies at that temple.

She is recalled from the school for an arranged marriage.  The prince she’s marrying is from another nation, in a greener, forested type land.

They get married and she’s relieved to find he’s kind and also has an affinity for fire. Her father also has some of her servants sent with her so she has people that understand her, since her new kingdom speaks another language.  She knows his language; he doesn’t know hers.

Against some people in his kingdom, he has a forge area set up for her to keep studying her magic and some things happen.

I don’t remember much beyond that other than some intrigue at court - an advisor is against her.

There is more than one book.  I remember her sister, the water-priest, sending a message using her powers, and some overthrowing of her family and murder. The sister also ends up as high priestess of the water (air?) temple.

The first book was in the 80s; not sure when the others came out.  Could be late 80s, early 90s.

I believe the first book had the word Fire in it, or some reference to heat.  I can’t remember any characters' names but I remember the great detail the author told about having to wear a certain form of leggings in the grasslands; otherwise the grass would cut your legs.

Comment: That is a very good first question! If any additional details come up, feel free to [edit] them in. We have additional prompts at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question that may help elicit details you had not thought of.